# PHP strip punctuation

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have this:

```
$hello = "Hello, is StackOverflow a helpful website!? Yes!";
```

and I want to strip punctuation so it outputs as:

```
hello_is_stackoverflow_a_helpful_website_yes
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
# to keep letters & numbers
$s = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '_', $s); # or...
$s = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]+/i', '_', $s);

# to keep letters only
$s = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '_', $s); 

# to keep letters, numbers & underscore
$s = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $s);

# same as third example; suggested by @tchrist; ^\w = \W
$s = preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $s);
```

for string

```
$s = "Hello, is StackOverflow a helpful website!? Yes!";
```

result (for all examples) is

> Hello_is_StackOverflow_a_helpful_website_Yes_

Enjoy!

Comment: Hmmm... but if I have `Hello, world!` I'll get `hello__world` when there is suppose to be one underscore for space not... two.

Comment: What an odd way to write `\W`!

Answer (score 18):

```
function strip_punctuation($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[:punct:]+/", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace(" +", "_", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

First the string is converted to lower case, then punctuation is removed, then spaces are replaced with underscores (this will handle one or more spaces, so if someone puts two spaces it will be replaced by only one underscore).

Comment: Isn’t `\pP` the modern way to specify punctuation?

Comment: @tchrist the most compatible and readable way (across POSIX, GNU, and PCRE regexp) is to use POSIX character classes like `[:alnum:]` and `[:punct:]`. `\pP`relies on Unicode stuff, idk how that works in PHP considering that PHP has awful unicode support.

Comment: If you want *readable*, then you’d use the full property name: `\p{General_Category=Punctuation}`, which is usually abbreviated as though it were a binary property, like `\p{Punctuation}`. Unfortunately PCRE doesn’t have good Unicode property support. The reason I would never trust POSIX charclasses is because they’re too subject to breakage based on vendor locales and user settings. It almost never handles Unicode correctly, even though this is required by [UTS#18’s RL1.2](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties). I mistrust and mislike anything that doesn’t do Unicode.

Comment: And as for *compatible*, you definitely need Unicode properties not flakey old POSIX charclasses.  That’s because Unicode properties are a lot *more* portable than the POSIX charclasses can ever hope to be, because the Unicode `\pP` “punctuation property” **always works on all Unicode punctuation,** no matter *what* sort of silly locale setting is or is not in play or how well the vendor has implemented them or whether they have kept up with the Unicode Standard, which they are all hopelessly very slow at.

Comment: For some reason, /[:punct:]+/ threw syntax errors, however /[[:punct:]]+/ did not.

Answer (score 11):

Without regular expressions:

```
<?php
  $hello = "Hello, is StackOverflow a helpful website!? Yes!"; // original string
  $unwantedChars = array(',', '!', '?'); // create array with unwanted chars
  $hello = str_replace($unwantedChars, '', $hello); // remove them
  $hello = strtolower($hello); // convert to lowercase
  $hello = str_replace(' ', '_', $hello); // replace spaces with underline
  echo $hello; // outputs: hello_is_stackoverflow_a_helpful_website_yes
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/', '', $str);
```

I don't know if that's more broad than you're looking for, but it sounds like what you're trying to do.

I also notice you've replaced spaces with underscores in your sample. The code I'd use for that is:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $str);
```

Note that this will also collapse multiple spaces into one underscore.