# PHP strip punctuation keep apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

Like [PHP strip punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5689918/1112440), but I want to keep the apostrophe.
Example:

```
I'm a student, but I don't like the school. I'll quit school.
```

The string after strip should be:

```
I'm a student but I don't like the school I'll quit school
```

How can I do that with regular expression or other ways?

Comment: I tried $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\']/', '', $string); It seems not useful. My string is from a html page. apostrophe is &#8217;  For example, Don't = Don&#8217;t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support all Unicode punctuation characters as well then use this regex:

```
$str = preg_replace("#((?!')\pP)+#", '', $str);
```

This regex is matching Unicode punctuation character class `\pP` and match will avoid apostrophe character using negative lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adaptation of the first example:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\' ]+/i', '', $string);
```