# Can't get a function to work, have tried everything. Involves stripping punctuation and spaces

Tags: php, function, syntax

I am trying to remove the punctuation from a variable and it's not working, I have tried everything I can think of. I've very tired and I'm sure it's something I'm just not seeing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
$memberlinksafe = $_POST["entity_name"];

function strip_punctuation($memberlinksafe) {
    $memberlinksafe = strtolower($memberlinksafe);
    $memberlinksafe = preg_replace("/[:punct:]+/", "", $memberlinksafe);
    $memberlinksafe = str_replace(" +", "", $memberlinksafe);
    return $memberlinksafe;
}
```

What am I not seeing? It's just returning the original `$_POST` variable

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing: `$memberlinksafe = strip_punctuation($_POST["entity_name"]);`

Comment: where are you calling the function?

Comment: Removing punctuation marks will not prevent your database from being attacked. You should be using PDO and bind parameters. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Since it is an upvoted answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689918/php-strip-punctuation, I'm pretty sure it might come from your call to this function.

Comment: OMG! I feel like such a fool! I need to go to bed. Thank you!!

Comment: @Incognito who says he's even using a database? there are enough actual php + mysql questions with comments like that; we don't need to make them on questions unrelated to databases too.

Comment: @Incognito I use prepared statements with mysqli. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: side note: does using posix named classes like that (`:punct:`) even work in vanilla php?

Comment: Do POSIX classes even work in preg_replace? I didn't think so.

Comment: @Mimo looks like they do, but you need double square brackets, not single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why

```
$memberlinksafe = str_replace(" +", "", $memberlinksafe);
```

and not

```
// This function removes spaces, \t (tabs), \r and \n. All are spaces!
$memberlinksafe = preg_replace('~[\\s]+~', '', $memberlinksafe);
```

for stripping spaces?

**UPDATE**:

```
// Remove punctuation
$memberlinksafe = preg_replace('~[[:punct:]]+~', '', $memberlinksafe);
// Remove spaces
$memberlinksafe = preg_replace('~[\\s]+~', '', $memberlinksafe);
// Lowercase
$memberlinksafe = strtolower($memberlinksafe);
```

or do:

```
// Keep only alphanumerics and lowercase it
$memberlinksafe = strtolower(preg_replace('~[^[:alnum:]]+~', '', $memberlinksafe));
```

**WHY NOT `\W`**

Because this:

```
// outputs 'testing_something'
var_dump(preg_replace('~[\\W]+~', '', 'testing_something'));
// outputs 'testingsomething'
var_dump(preg_replace('~[[:punct:]]+~', '', 'testing_something'));
```

`_` is actually punctuation.

Comment: He's stripping out the `+` not the space.

Comment: 1) this isn't an answer, 2) `str_replace(" +", "", $memberlinksafe);` doesn't strip spaces, it strips `" +"`, and 3) `str_replace(" ", "", $memberlinksafe)` is much faster than using a regex in the first place

Comment: @sgroves \t is a space, \r and \n are also spaces. My RegExp clears them all ;)

Comment: ... none of those are spaces. they're whitespace characters, but not spaces. at any rate, the OP wasn't trying to strip spaces in the first place.

Comment: What I'm actually wanting to do is remove all punctuation, spaces and make the string lowercase.

Comment: in that case i'm not sure what you're trying to do with `str_replace(" +", "", $memberlinksafe)` then ... why not something simple like `strtolower(preg_replace('|\W|', '', $memberlinksafe))` to do all that at once instead?

Comment: @JeffPeak I updated the code. See if this fits. It's commented.

Comment: Through all of the comments and suggestions I've figured out the issue. Thank you everyone for your help. Now I am going to bed.

Comment: still not sure why you'd use `[\\s]+` as your pattern to match whitespace over just `\s`, but i suppose it does the same thing ... i downvoted because this doesn't answer the OP's question in any way (and because `\t`, `\r`, and `\n` are *not* spaces but rather **whitespace** characters

Comment: @sgroves Because, even if in single quotes, proper practice is to escape \\ too. It works both ways, but I have my coding style. I double \\ in single quotes too.

Comment: @CodeAngry weird, never seen anyone do that

Comment: @sgroves Yes, you can use \W too but this is an example to learn from. I broke it down in pieces easy to digest. He might want to keep spaces later on. It's didactic :)

Comment: `\W` seems far easier to digest to me. "match all non-word characters", which is exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: @sgroves Made an update just for you. Hope it clears things out. _ is considered a word part in both PHP and C character functions.

Comment: makes sense to me. still not upvoting because this doesn't answer the posted question :P

Comment: @sgroves (facepalm) I don't care. I don't beg for points here. If it helped the poster, it's great.

Comment: @sgroves Haters gonna hate ;)

Comment: @CodeAngry - downvoting is not hating - it's just a message here. It would be nice if everyone declared their downvotes but it isn't required. By all means do enquire after the reason, but "haters gonna hate" is rarely the case on Stack Exchange. (Downvotes only take away -2 to an upvote's +10, so it's not worth worrying about anyway).