# How to strip a sentence just keep letters, numbers, spaces

Tags: regex

I have a lot of sentences that need to be cleaned up from all the special characters and punctuations (I want to keep just the letters and numbers and spaces), for example:

```
$string = "TB Avrupa ve Türkiye'nin en iyi oranlari ile Lider Bahis Sitesi!!";
$final_title = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $string);
```

This remove everything (with spaces)
I need to keep spaces can i add anything to the previous line to achieve this ??

Expected output :

```
TB Avrupa ve Türkiyenin en iyi oranlari ile Lider Bahis Sitesi
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Wow, all the answers around the same time had the same answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689918/php-strip-punctuation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `I want to keep just the letters and numbers and spaces`

You can use this regex to remove everything other than english letters, digits and spaces:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z\d ]+/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: What part of the regexp makes it case-insensitive? Is it /i?

Comment: @DavidBrossard: `a-z` part otherwise to avoid `/i` one need to use `/[^A-Za-z\d ]+/`

Comment: @DavidBrossard yes the `i` at the end specify that.

Comment: @DavidBrossard The `/` signals the start and end of the pattern.  The `i` is then the case-insensitive option.

Answer (score 2):

Just include any characters you want to keep:

```
'/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i'
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change your regex to this:

```
$final_title = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i', '', $string);
```

This will keep numbers and spaces.

---

I do not know exactly what your requirements are, however, `ü` is a valid letter in some languages.

If you want to keep those as well, you would need to make a regex like so:

```
$final_title = preg_replace('/[\p{L}0-9 ]+/i', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Z^a-z^0-9^şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ ]+/i', '', $string);
```