# Handle unicode while removing/replacing non-word characters

Tags: php, regex, string, unicode, preg-replace

I would like to remove punctuations and symbols (non word characters generally) from a string that has unicode (non-ASCII) characters.

e.g. `New $Orléans` to `New Orléans` or `NewOrléans` (if space is removed)

The methods I have come cross so far use `\W` or `\w` (see [PHP strip punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689918/php-strip-punctuation))

The challenge I have is retaining unicode. If I use `\W` the `Î` on `Île-de-France` gets removed/replaced:

`preg_replace('/\W+/', "-", 'Île-de-France')` gives `-le-de-France`

Is it possible to remove non-word characters and still handle non-ASCII characters that are word characters?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `'/[^\p{M}\w]+/u'`.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/hV2qA2/1

Comment: If you need to work with combining marks use my suggestion. Else, your question is a duplicate as there are so many similar questions here about the `\u`  modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using `\u` does the trick. I had already seen `\u` but didn't know what it was for. I also tried it on an example using `character classes` instead of `POSIX`, and it failed. The solution looks simple but on a search there was no immediate clue. Probably you could post you  comment as an answer. It could help somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the safest regex to handle Unicode letters when removing non-word characters, use

```
'/[^\p{M}\w]+/u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eW2vO6/1)

The point is that *by all means* you need the `/u` modifier (enables PCRE engine to treat the pattern and the string as a Unicode string), and `\W` does not match *combining marks*.

If you do not need to worry about the combining marks, you can use `'/\W+/u'` regex to remove non-word characters.

Also, see the [`/u` modifier reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **`u (PCRE_UTF8)`**
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.