# Create a php search page

Tags: php

I am trying to create a page that will search other pages!
All is working except a detail!
Here is part of the code:

```
$a = file_get_contents('a.html');
$b = explode(' ' , $a);
$phpsearch = $_POST['htmlsearch'];
if ($phpsearch != null) {
   foreach ($a as $key) {
       if ($phpsearch == $key) {
            echo '<b>Search for ' . $phpsearch . ' - <a href=\'abc.html\' target=\'_blank\'>aaa</a></b><br>';
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Search shows nothing if there is a comma or a dot, next to the word!

I have tried this on line 5 -> if ($phpsearch == $key . ',')
It is not working!
Can I merge variable $key with a symbol or exclude symbols from variable $a?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the punctuation from $a try these regular expressions:

```
# to keep letters & numbers
$a = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '_', $a); # or...
$a = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]+/i', '_', $a);


# to keep letters only
$a = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '_', $a); 

# to keep letters, numbers & underscore
$a = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '_', $a);

# same as third example; suggested by @tchrist
$a = preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $a);
```

Adapted from accepted answer at [citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689918/php-strip-punctuation)